# Formatting time for ical export

Tags: date, datetime, time, icalendar, rfc5545

I have created a calendar in jquery that exports to ical. However, I am having some issues with the datetime.

The ical export script expects the date/time in this format: 19970714T170000Z.

Does anybody know what this is and how I should prepare my string?

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Reading the RFC ([link](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.3.5))
gives :

> 3.3.5.  Date-Time

> [...]

> date-time  = date "T" time

> The "DATE-TIME" value type expresses time values in three forms:

> FORM #1: DATE WITH LOCAL TIME
> For example, the following represents January 18, 1998, at 11 PM:
> 19980118T230000

> FORM #2: DATE WITH UTC TIME
> CAPITAL LETTER Z suffix character, to the time value.
> For example, the following represents January 19, 1998, at 0700 UTC:
> 19980119T070000Z

> FORM #3: DATE WITH LOCAL TIME AND TIME ZONE REFERENCE
> TZID=America/New_York:19980119T020000

> DTSTART:19970714T133000                   ; Local time
> DTSTART:19970714T173000Z                  ; UTC time
> DTSTART;TZID=America/New_York:19970714T133000
> ; Local time and time
> ; zone reference

Answer (score 2):

It's almost like toISOString

```
function formatDateTime(date) {
  const year = date.getUTCFullYear();
  const month = pad(date.getUTCMonth() + 1);
  const day = pad(date.getUTCDate());
  const hour = pad(date.getUTCHours());
  const minute = pad(date.getUTCMinutes());
  const second = pad(date.getUTCSeconds());
  return `${year}${month}${day}T${hour}${minute}${second}Z`;
}

function pad(i) {
  return i < 10 ? `0${i}` : `${i}`;
}

// Example:
const date = new Date('2017-05-31T11:46:54.216Z');
date.toISOString()   // '2017-05-31T11:46:54.216Z'
date.toJSON()        // '2017-05-31T11:46:54.216Z'
formatDateTime(date) // '20170531T114654Z'
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a `date` "July 1, 2022" and a `time` "1:30 PM", and wanted it into the ical format, from a browser console.

```
const date = "July 1, 2022";
const time = "1:30 PM";

function calendarTimeFormat(date) {
    const year = Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { year: 'numeric', timeZone: 'utc' }).format(date);
    const month = Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { month: '2-digit', timeZone: 'utc' }).format(date);
    const day = Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { day: '2-digit', timeZone: 'utc' }).format(date);
    const hour = Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { hour: '2-digit', timeZone: 'utc', hour12: false }).format(date).split(' ')[0];
    const minute = Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { minute: '2-digit', timeZone: 'utc' }).format(date).split(' ')[0];
    return year + month + day + "T" + hour + minute + "00Z";
}

const d = Date.parse(`${date} ${time}`);
console.log(calendarTimeFormat(d);
```

Answer (score -3):

So to answer the question to convert to this format in JQuery you can do the following.

```
var n = d.toISOString();
```