# ical file issue

Tags: java, lotus-notes, icalendar

This issue is really frustrating me.
I am developping a webapp that creates ical files for users.

The issue that I am facing, is whenever the ical event repeates weekly or daily or monthly, the start time shows up wrong in Lotus Notes.
As you can see in the following file start time is 9:00 am, however in lotus notes (email client with calendar) this is showing completely wrong (as 5:00 am). I tried adding a timezone to the DTSTART and DTEND, but that doesn't fix things, but creates more problems.
Is there something wrong perhaps in syntax; with the way I am generating the ical files?
Also the endtime is showeing up correctly for some reason, only the start time is wrong.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Test event//iCal4j 1.0//EN
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20120730T124016Z
DTSTART:20120730T090014
DTEND:20120730T100014
SUMMARY:Test Meeting
UID:3988c7e1-4dd1-4e0c-b132-e829beac0592
LOCATION:test: at CR
DESCRIPTION:
RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;COUNT=30
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Comment: Did you check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10518804/formatting-time-for-ical-export

Comment: can you also share how you added the timezone information? also when loading the file in google calendar it works as expected, is your problem only with lotus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, I just needed to specify a Vtimezone.
If someone else runs into this problem; something like the following would fix it.

```
> BEGIN:VTIMEZONE TZID:Eastern BEGIN:STANDARD DTSTART:19501105T020000
> TZOFFSETFROM:-0400 TZOFFSETTO:-0500
> RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMINUTE=0;BYHOUR=2;BYDAY=1SU;BYMONTH=11
> END:STANDARD BEGIN:DAYLIGHT DTSTART:19500312T020000 TZOFFSETFROM:-0500
> TZOFFSETTO:-0400
> RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMINUTE=0;BYHOUR=2;BYDAY=2SU;BYMONTH=3 END:DAYLIGHT
> END:VTIMEZONE
```